# What is the meaning of "sneeze up a storm" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "sneeze up a storm" in the following sentence(Source: THE BIG SNEEZE by WILLJAM VAN HORN),

> "Goodness, Bert," said Charlie.
>
> "With sneeze like that, you could **sneeze up a storm**!"
>
> It so happened that the sky was growing dark and stormy-looking.
>
> But the three dinosaurs didn't notice anything.
>
> They were waiting to see if Bert would sneeze again.

?

Does "you could sneeze up a storm" mean "you sneezed. A storm arose after(because of) your sneezing" or "A storm arose. You sneezed toward the storm. The storm disappeared because of your sneezing" ?

Comment: Idiomatically, you can ***talk / conjure / stir / blow / raise** a storm* - meaning to ***create*** a (usually, *metaphorical*) storm. Charlie's usage is a one-off coinage based on those (he's whimsically suggesting Bert's sneezing is so violent it could actually influence the weather and create a storm). So it's not a matter of the sneeze ***stopping*** a storm - it's whether it might ***start*** one.

Comment: If so, Does "up" in "you could sneeze up a storm" mean "to create" ? Does "you could sneeze up a storm" mean "you could sneeze to create a storm" ?

Comment: For all I know, your cited writer is the only person in history who has every said anything like *You could sneeze up a storm*, so we have to be a little bit careful about saying what it would actually "mean". All you can really say is the speaker is "punning" on the well-established [***conjure** up a storm*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22conjure+up+a+storm%22), which means ***start/create*** a (nearly always metaphorical) storm / fuss / controversy. But in your cited usage the storm is apparently ***literal*** anyway. It's just fanciful / facetious phrasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particle **up** there conveys the abstract idea of *to instantiate* or *to complete*  in connection with the verb.  A storm is being created as a *byproduct* of the activity.

P.S. In colloquial American English, and possibly also in British English, a number of verbs can combine with **up** and **a storm**.

> Where's Fido?
>   --He's out in the back yard, barking up a storm.
>
> The toddler was so cute as she sang up a storm.
>
> The high-school friends when they met at the reunion talked up a storm.
>
> Those kids were doing the jitterbug, dancing up a storm.
>
> Grandma was moving about the kitchen, stirring pots, checking the oven, chopping vegetables, cooking up a storm. She looked forward to the holiday when the whole family would be together.

The phrase `{VERB} up a storm` means to "engage in {verb}'s action in a very unrestrained manner, or very energetically".  To say that it is producing a storm is a great exaggeration, of course.

Comment: If so, Does "sneeze up a storm" mean "sneeze to complete(create) a storm" ? Does "whip up a few snacks" mean "whip to complete(create) a few snacks"? Does "barking up a storm" mean "barking to complete(create) a storm" ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I don't like the infinitive there, **whip to complete** as the storm is a *byproduct* not an intentional product of the activity.  The activity is being engaged in with such energy that it is creating a storm.